# Assign some collection variable to a temporary variable in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two arrays inside Angular scope - tags, and accounts. Items inside each array have the same structure. I also have one template to show items from both accounts and tags arrays in the same way. But as collections have different names - tags and accounts, I have to use it like this (Jade):

```
  div(ng-switch on="activeEntriesFilter")
    div(ng-switch-when="accounts")
      ul.items-list
        li.item-row(ng-repeat="account in accounts", ng-click="setActiveGroupFilterItem(account)")
          span.title {{account.value.title}}
    div(ng-switch-when="tags")
      ul.items-list
        li.item-row(ng-repeat="tag in tags", ng-click="setActiveGroupFilterItem(tag)")
          span.title {{tag.value.title}}
```

As you can see, lists have the same structure so the code is being duplicated. What I would like to see here instead is something like assigning accounts or tags array to some temporary variable, e.g. items, then show deal with that temporary variable when creating the list.

How can I do it the most beautiful and logic way?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
div(ng-switch on="activeEntriesFilter")
    ul.items-list
        li.item-row(ng-repeat="entry in (activeEntriesFilter == 'accounts' && accounts || tags)", ng-click="setActiveGroupFilterItem(entry)")
            span.title {{entry.value.title}}
```

They will be introducing ternary clause in 1.2 but for now you can use this I believe.